# Retrieve all not logged in users from mysql tables (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables listed below:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|                             v3_customer                                |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+
| customer_id | firstname |   lastname   |             email             |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|           1 | Piet      | Pizza        | piet.pizza@example.com        |
|           2 | Klaas     | Hein         | klaas.hein@example.com        |
|           3 | Henk      | Crowdcontrol | henk.crowdcontrol@example.com |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+

+-------------+-------------+---------------+
|           v3_customer_activity            |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| activity_id | customer_id |      key      |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
|           1 |           1 | login         |
|           2 |           1 | order_account |
|           3 |           2 | login         |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

What i want is to select all customers which haven't logged in yet (note the **login** key in `v3_customer_activity`). So in this case that would be the customer with **customer_id: 3**

I'm using a mysql database.

I have tried using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v3_customer.customer_id, v3_customer.firstname, v3_customer.lastname, v3_customer.email FROM `v3_customer` JOIN v3_customer_activity ON v3_customer.customer_id = v3_customer_activity.customer_id WHERE v3_customer.customer_id != (SELECT v3_customer_activity.customer_id FROM v3_customer_activity)
```

In the hope it would iterate between the rows found in the subquery.
This resulted in an error telling me a subquery may not contain multiple rows.

**TL;DR**

What I want is to retrieve every customer from `v3_customer` who is not listed in the table `v3_customer_activity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select v3_customer.* from v3_customer
left join v3_customer_activity on v3_customer.customer_id=v3_customer_activity.customer_id
where v3_customer_activity.customer_id is null;
```

Left join `v3_customer` table with `v3_customer_activity` and filter records which are not matched.

Comment: I didn't know v3_customer.* is valid mysql, the more you know!

Comment: @Baklap4: No Worries. My Pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select v3_customer.* from v3_customer 
where v3_customer.customer_id not in (SELECT v3_customer_activity.customer_id FROM v3_customer_activity)
```